# Unable to access child component properties with ViewChild in angular 11

Tags: angular

I am upgrading my application to the latest version of angular.

And below I have pasted all `package`:

```
{
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
}
```

And using `@viewChild` as:

```
@ViewChild(childComponent,{static: true})_childCmpt: childComponent;
```

And I console `_childCmpt` variable on button click then `undefined` is printed.

```
 clickEvent(){
     console.log(this._childCmpt); //undefined
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild`.